# Special characters in text file with c#

Tags: c#, text

I'm creating this file:

```
StreamWriter swClifor = new StreamWriter("test.txt",true, Encoding.ASCII);
string cString = "5° ENNIO" // It comes from a Postgresql database
```

Write cString: with:

```
swClifor.WriteLine(cString);
```

and close stream:

```
swClifor.Close();
```

When i read file with Notepad++ (UTF-8) I see this:5° ENNIO
When i read file with Notepad++ (ANSI) I see 5Â° ENNIO.
When the file destination program reads the text it sees 5Â ° ENNIO and goes into error.

This is the complete problem.

Comment: Is the degrees sign an ASCII character?

Comment: Encoding.ASCII doesn't contain you special characters so they never get saved.

Comment: Also try 
StreamWriter swClifor = new StreamWriter("test.txt",true, Encoding.UTF8);
Not work…..

Comment: How are you *reading* the file?

Comment: I use Notepad++

Comment: What @john is trying to say is that ° is **not** `Encoding.ASCII` and you must specify an `Encoding` that allows that character. `Encoding.UTF8` will work, why do you think it “not work”

Comment: Because if I open the file I read the character 5Â° and the length of the string is not correct.

Comment: Please edit and update the question to be more specific. You write a text file in C# using `Unicode` encodings and read it with Notepad++. Are you claiming that notepad++ doesn't read it correctly? (PS. Forget about ASCII, don't go there).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
using (StreamWriter swClifor = new StreamWriter("test.txt", true, Encoding.Unicode))
{
     string cString = "5° ENNIO";
     swClifor.WriteLine(cString);
}
```

Comment: No don't work, if you read the file with UTF-8, do not see the spacial char, but if you switch to ANSI, see 5Â° ENNIO. (Notepad++)

Comment: Infoservice, Where is the ° symbol on this [ANSI chart](http://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC57419.gif)? What do you expect to happen to two-byte characters that aren't represented by the encoding type you're reading the data with? ASCII stupid question, get a stupid ANSI after all.

Comment: @Infoservice Um, yes it does. Why TF would you read a Unicode encoded page in UTF-8 and expect it to show correctly? I opened the output with NotePad++ and it shows fine.

Comment: @john, the origin of the string is a Postgresql database with code page Win1252. In the database the string appears as 5th ENNIO, in the datatable it appears as 5th ENNIO, when I write it on file, reading it in UTF-8, it appears as 5th ENNIO, reading it in ANSI, it appears as 5th ENNIO. So I think the problem is the way it is written

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc, the problem is that I write the file, but another program reads it and goes wrong for it.